I have a problem launching one job after another successfully finishes in GitLab CI
I have GitLab CI config like this
image: hmmmk/androidbuildenv-jdk17-api33:latest

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

# TODO: replace with assembleRelease
build_main:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "main"'
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main"'
      when: never

build_develop:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "develop"'
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "develop"'
      when: never

deploy_develop_telegram:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apk_file=$(find app/build/outputs/ -name "*.apk" | head -n 1)
    - echo "Sending $apk_file to Telegram..."
    - curl -F chat_id="-1" -F document=@"$apk_file" -F caption="New APK build from CI" https://api.telegram.org/botid/sendDocument
  needs: ["build_develop"]


And the thing is that deploy_develop_telegram is never called after build_develop successfully finishes. I don't even see deploy_develop_telegram in GitLab dashboard. I tried different approaches also with rules and needs but nothing seems to be working. No error messages, nothing, looks like GitLab just ignores this job.
What am I doing wrong?

have you tried to change needs: ["build_develop"], to just needs: ["build"]?

the when: never rule in build_develop and build_main can prevent the job from running and thus stopping the deploy_develop_telegram job from appearing.

@liaifat85 how is that? This rule is applied to build_develop as I understand. And build_develop is passing successfully all the time

The issue is related to job rules. Somehow, GitLab CI ignores dependant jobs if their rules block doesn't match the block from the job they depend on. So solution for this will be just adding:
rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "develop"'
      when: always

to deploy_develop_telegram job.
The only problem is that I don't understand the reason behind this, cause for me, it should not work like this, because needs already defines the actual "rule" for this job. If somebody can explain this better, please leave a comment.

In what workflow do you expect this pipeline to run successfully ?
To me the rules for build_main and build_developare preventingdeploy_develop_telegram` from running.
Furthermore, you repeat both build jobs with no visible differences in the job's script. Perhaps you should move the rules in deploy_develop_telegram job to prevent it from running instead.

I do not repeat both jobs since each of jobs runs for Merge Request with different targets: one for main branch and the other one is for develop
